# c# string convert char

Tags: c#, string, char

I am new to C#, both of the values below are valid, what is the difference between them ?

```
// 1st option:
string value;
// ...
char tt = Convert.ToChar(value);
```

```
// 2nd option:
string value;
// ...
char tt = char.Parse(value);
```

What is the difference between the two ?

Comment: [Char.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.parse?view=net-7.0) ... [Convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Both are semantically out in left field. Functionally, they get the first character. That can be done with `value[0]` or, if you need it to throw an error when there's more than one character, `value.First()` (LINQ). Both of those have better semantics than "conversion" and "parsing". Semantics are important because we need to write code so that future maintainers (including ourselves) understand what it's doing and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real difference.

Both [`Convert.ToChar(string value)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tochar?view=net-7.0), and [`char.Parse(string s)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.parse?view=net-7.0) expect a string with 1 character, and throw [`FormatException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formatexception?view=net-7.0) if this is not the case.

If the string does contain 1 character, they both return it as a `char`.

**Note**:
The answer above refers to the specific overloads that you mentioned in the question.
As you can see in the link above `Convert.ToChar` has other overloads (e.g. `ToChar(String, IFormatProvider)`), which offer options that you don't have with `char.Parse`.

Comment: Yeah I think you are correct.  Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem @Tarazed. I also learn new things here everyday ;-)

Comment: However, Convert.ToChar() does offer more overloads/data types and Convert.ToChar(String) supports culture.

Comment: They work the same as the Linq extension `char tt = value.Single();`.

Comment: @Tarazed `Convert.ToChar(String)` (which the OP asked about) is a specific overload. But you are right that ``Convert.ToChar` has other overload.

Comment: The overload `Convert.ToChar(string, IFormatProvider?)` ignores its second argument, though.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen the OP mentioned specifically the overload with only 1 `string` parameter. Anyway I added a note about other overloads.